# Create custom animatable property in UIView / UIControl subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

There are a few questions and answers on StackOverflow about [custom animatable properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192816/create-a-custom-animatable-property), but I haven't been able to effectively use their answers / solutions.

In short, I'd like to have a `UIControl` with some properties that I can put in an animation block (e.g. `[UIView animateWithDuration:...`) and have it behave as some of UIKit's controls (e.g. `UISlider`) do.

For example, I'd like to do something like,

```
TASlider *myCustomSlider = [[TASlider alloc] init];
myCustomSlider.value = 0.f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.f animations:^{
    myCustomSlider.value = 0.f;
}];
```

and have it “just work”. `TASlider` would be a `UIControl` subclass and it would have a public property `value` and a private property `myKnob` (which is a `UIView` or `CALayer` subclass). The above code would animate the private subview or sublayer `myKnob` when the `value` property was modified in the animation block.

I've researched this a bit but I guess I can't quite put the pieces together to do what I'd like.

Could someone put together a “Hello World” of custom animatable `CALayer` properties on a `UIView` / `UIControl` subclass?

Comment: I think the other answer you refer to, is pretty good for doing what you want. 1. Subclass CALayer, 2. Create a @dynamic property, 3. Override setNeedsDisplayForKey. Like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2396461/2462469

Comment: @RobvanderVeer that is almost a full answer, please post! This question in for UIView, that one is CALayers, and you are providing the glue