# Change foregroundColor of a UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to change the foregroundColor of a UIView?

I'm creating an arrow using an UIView (drawRect) like this ">", with a clear background, only two black lines. This is working great. But afterwards I would like to change the color of the ">" from black to red, for example. Would be nice to have an animation in it, like a gradient from black to red, using CAKeyframeAnimation. I can do it for borderColor and backgroundColor but these properties are not the ones that I'm looking for.

I'm changing the borderColor of another UIView using this block of animation. I would like to do the same with the foregroundColor but it's not working in iOS.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation* colorAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"borderColor"];
NSArray* colorValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,  nil];
colorAnim.values = colorValues;
colorAnim.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
colorAnim.duration = 5.0;
colorAnim.repeatCount = 1;
[self.myView.layer addAnimation:colorAnim forKey:@"borderColor"];
```

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIView` class does not have a `foregroundColor` property, so you have to implement it yourself. In your UIView subclass interface, define the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *foregroundColor;
```

In your subclass implementation, override the `setForegroundColor:` setter method:

```
- (void)setForegroundColor:(UIColor *)newForegoundColor
{
    _foregroundColor = newForegroundColor;
    [self setNeedsDisplay]; // This is need so that drawRect: is called
}
```

In whichever initialiser you're are using in the subclass, set the `foregroundColor` property to a default:

```
self.foregroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

In your `drawRect:` implementation, use the `foregroundColor` property to stroke the chevron you are drawing:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.foregroundColor.CGColor);
```

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you very much for the answer. I did everything you suggested and the new property is working great, but the animation is not changing the color of the subview. I'm calling like this:

`CAKeyframeAnimation* colorAnim2 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"foregroundColor"];`
`colorAnim2.values = colorValues;`
`colorAnim2.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;`
`colorAnim2.duration = 5.0;`
`colorAnim2.repeatCount = 1;`
`[self.balloonTriangleBorder.layer addAnimation:colorAnim forKey:@"foregroundColor"];`

Comment: To have a custom property be animatable, you have to do your drawing in the `CALayer` subclass and [override `needsDisplayForKey:`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192816/create-a-custom-animatable-property).