# WKInterfaceSlider behavior like in Watch’s Now Playing

Tags: ios, slider, watchkit, apple-watch

How can I implement same border appearing behavior over a slider (or group) when user changes volume value by digital crown? I have insert a [video](https://gfycat.com/DopeyPiercingEskimodog) which demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented this by using ValueAnimation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34849892/3824335) question. Instead of using `NSTimer` I use GCD-based timer to have more flexibility. See [RXTimer](https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/8550768) or [DispatchTimer](https://github.com/ambientlight/DispatchTimer) for more info.