# UIButton state transition animation not working for setEnabled or setHighlighted

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiviewanimationtransition

**Update**

The animation is working for `setEnabled=NO`.

The animation for `setEnabled=YES` is being triggered when `UIScrollView` is scrolling, the `UIButton` is inside the scrollview and the animation for `setEnabled=NO` is being triggered when `UIScrollView` is done scrolling.

So, I think the reason why animation for `setEnabled=YES` is not working is because the view is moving. I am not sure but this seems to be the only logical explanation from what I have found so far. I did a test with `dispatch_after()` and the animation worked for `setEnabled` too, in other words the animation is working if it is being triggered when the view is not moving.

**What I need to do ?**

I have two different background images for `UIButton` one for `UIControlStateNormal` and another for `UIControlStateDisabled`.

I want a effect where UIButton slowly transitions over from one state to another

**What have I been doing ?**

```
BOOL enableDisable = YES;
[UIView transitionWithView:((UIButton*)object)
                                          duration:3.3
                                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                        animations:^{ [((UIButton*)object) setEnabled:enableDisable]; }
                                        completion:nil];
```

**The Problem**

UIButton transforms to `setEnabled=NO` state over the duration but no matter what I put in the `options` `setEnabled` happens almost instantly.

is there something I am missing ?

Thanks in advance for your time and response.

Comment: declare enableDisable as block type object.

Comment: @johnykumar not sure what you mean.

Comment: it is working when i run

Comment: set your duration to 10

Comment: it works for `setEnable=NO`

Comment: take enableDisable bool

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, enable or disabled state for `UIView` aren't part of animatable properties in apple docs. The animatable properties are:

```
frame, center, bounds, transform, alpha, backgroundColor, contentStretch
```

Reference here: [UIView animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html)

However if you want to create custom property for animation, you can have a look at this post which describes a way to achieve it. [Create a custom animatable property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14192816/593709)

Comment: `it is working for setEnabled = NO;` and this is what surprises me :(

Comment: I agree with Adil, you should create your own UIControl or UIView, but use composition, do not subclass UIButton.

Comment: Or just make your custom UIButton class, and create your own custom animation: something like `[button setEnabled:YES animated:YES]`

Comment: I am not sure animatable property are relevant here. We are talking about `transitionWithView:...` not `animateWithDuration:...`

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that your code works as expected both for the transition

enabled: NO -> YES

and for the transition

enabled: YES -> NO

So, my guess is that something else is happening in your app that somehow interferes with the transition. Try defining a completion block like:

```
...
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"FINISHED? %@", finished?@"YES":@"NO");
} ];
```

and add a trace log before the `transitionWith` call or inside the animation block to check how long the transition runs from start to completion.

My guess is that while the button is transitioning something else is happening that changes its state and as a secondary effect breaks the transition. I fear that without seeing more code, it will not be possible to help you further...

Comment: I am guessing the reason is the user interaction. Animation begins and stop instantly. I tried the same code with a explicit trigger and it worked perfect but when it is triggered from gesture it does not work