# Animate Custom UIView Property in Swift

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, calayer

all!

I have created a circular progress view using `CoreGraphics` that looks and updates like so:

50%
[image]
75%
[image]

The class is a `UIView` class, and it has a variable called 'progress' that determines how much of the circle is filled in.

It works well, but I want to be able to animate changes to the progress variable so that the bar animates smoothly.

I have read from myriad examples that I need to have a `CALayer` class along with the View class, which I have made, however, it doesn't animate at all.

Two questions:

1. Can I keep the graphic I drew in `CoreGraphics`, or do I need to somehow redraw it in `CALayer`?
2. My current (attempted) solution crashes towards the bottom at: `anim.fromValue = pres.progress`. What's up?

   ```
   class CircleProgressView: UIView {
       @IBInspectable var backFillColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()
       @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()
       @IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()

       dynamic var progress: CGFloat = 0.00 {
           didSet {
               self.layer.setValue(progress, forKey: "progress")
           }
       }

       var distToDestination: CGFloat = 10.0
       @IBInspectable var arcWidth: CGFloat = 20
       @IBInspectable var outlineWidth: CGFloat = 5

       override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
           return CircleProgressLayer.self
       }

       override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

           var fillColor = self.fillColor

           if distToDestination < 3.0 {
               fillColor = UIColor.greenColor()
           } else {
               fillColor = self.fillColor
           }

           //Drawing the inside of the container

           //Drawing in the container
           let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)
           let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height) - 10
           let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π / 2
           let endAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π / 2 + 2 * π
           let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
           path.lineWidth = arcWidth
           backFillColor.setStroke()
           path.stroke()
           let fill = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.15)
           fill.setFill()
           path.fill()

           //Drawing the fill path. Same process
           let fillAngleLength =  (π) * progress
           let fillStartAngle = 3 * π / 2 - fillAngleLength
           let fillEndAngle = 3 * π / 2 + fillAngleLength

           let fillPath_fill = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2, startAngle: fillStartAngle, endAngle: fillEndAngle, clockwise: true)
           fillPath_fill.lineWidth = arcWidth
           fillColor.setStroke()
           fillPath_fill.stroke()

           //Drawing container outline on top
           let outlinePath_outer = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius / 2 - outlineWidth / 2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
           let outlinePath_inner = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius / 2 - arcWidth + outlineWidth / 2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
           outlinePath_outer.lineWidth = outlineWidth
           outlinePath_inner.lineWidth = outlineWidth
           strokeColor.setStroke()
           outlinePath_outer.stroke()
           outlinePath_inner.stroke()
       }
   }

   class CircleProgressLayer: CALayer {
       @NSManaged var progress: CGFloat

       override class func needsDisplayForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
           if key == "progress" {
               return true
           }
           return super.needsDisplayForKey(key)
       }

       override func actionForKey(key: String) -> CAAction? {
           if (key == "progress") {
               if let pres = self.presentationLayer() {
                   let anim: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: key)
                   anim.fromValue = pres.progress
                   anim.duration = 0.2
                   return anim
               }

           return super.actionForKey(key)
           } else {
               return super.actionForKey(key)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried just doing something like: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1431312&seqNum=5?

Comment: I believe that is what is happening in actionForKey() -> CAAction?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this out :)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let progressView = CircleProgressView(frame:CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 200))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 200, 100)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.tap), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
        view.addSubview(progressView)

        progressView.progress = 1.0
   }

    func tap() {
        if  progressView.progress == 0.5 {
            progressView.progress = 1.0
        } else {
            progressView.progress = 0.5
        }
    }
}

class CircleProgressView: UIView {

    dynamic var progress: CGFloat = 0.00 {
        didSet {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation()
            animation.keyPath = "progress"
            animation.fromValue = circleLayer().progress
            animation.toValue = progress
            animation.duration = Double(0.5)
            self.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "progress")
            circleLayer().progress = progress
        }
    }

    func circleLayer() ->  CircleProgressLayer {
        return self.layer as! CircleProgressLayer
    }

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return CircleProgressLayer.self
    }
}

class CircleProgressLayer: CALayer {
    @NSManaged var progress: CGFloat

    override class func needsDisplayForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
        if key == "progress" {
            return true
        }
        return super.needsDisplayForKey(key)
    }

    var backFillColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    var strokeColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    var distToDestination: CGFloat = 10.0
    var arcWidth: CGFloat = 20
    var outlineWidth: CGFloat = 5

    override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {
        super.drawInContext(ctx)

        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)

        //Drawing in the container
        let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)
        let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height) - 10
        let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 2
        let endAngle: CGFloat = 3 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 2 + 2 * CGFloat(M_PI)
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        path.lineWidth = arcWidth
        backFillColor.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
        let fill = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.15)
        fill.setFill()
        path.fill()

        //Drawing the fill path. Same process
        let fillAngleLength =  (CGFloat(M_PI)) * progress
        let fillStartAngle = 3 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 2 - fillAngleLength
        let fillEndAngle = 3 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 2 + fillAngleLength

        let fillPath_fill = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2, startAngle: fillStartAngle, endAngle: fillEndAngle, clockwise: true)
        fillPath_fill.lineWidth = arcWidth
        fillColor.setStroke()
        fillPath_fill.stroke()

        //Drawing container outline on top
        let outlinePath_outer = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius / 2 - outlineWidth / 2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        let outlinePath_inner = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius / 2 - arcWidth + outlineWidth / 2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        outlinePath_outer.lineWidth = outlineWidth
        outlinePath_inner.lineWidth = outlineWidth
        strokeColor.setStroke()
        outlinePath_outer.stroke()
        outlinePath_inner.stroke()

        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I know it can be frowned upon to provide example code but this worked like a charm. It looks like I had the right elements in the wrong places. Thanks for showing me how to draw a Core Graphics element in a CA Layer, and embed the animation into a didSet  :)

Comment: Good Job, I realy try so many times to make it works, most important thing is that marking your custom property with **@NSManaged**

Comment: @krosshj I spent two sleepless nights wondering why mine wasn't working. I was missing `@NSManaged` 

Comment: @krosshj It's a good day!

Answer (score 2):

Whilst AntonTheDev provides a great answer, his solution does not allow you to animate the CircularProgressView in an animation block, so you cant do neat things like:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, 
animations: {
    circularProgress.progress = 0.76
}, completion: nil)
```

There's a similar question here with a up to date **Swift 3** answer based on ideas from the accepted answer and [this](https://gist.github.com/nicklockwood/d374033b27c62662ac8d) post.
This is what the final solution looks like.

[image: the final product]

> [Swift 3 Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44961463/5038557)