# What's the meaning of progress keypath in CABasicAnimation?

Tags: ios, animation

A code snippet from https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress/blob/master/DACircularProgress/DACircularProgressView.m

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"progress"];
animation.duration = duration;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.progress];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:pinnedProgress];
animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + initialDelay;
animation.delegate = self;
[self.circularProgressLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"progress"];
```

But I could not find `progress` in the [offical document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html). Does the keypath need to be animatable property? What does the `progress` mean?

Comment: I think you might have misread the code. The `forKey:@"progress"` is "naming" the animation.

Comment: I mean the `progress` in `[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"progress"];`

Comment: Oops! My misreading, not yours! Was offscreen before edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19024971/916299) (which is coincidentally animating `progress` too):

> Firstly we need to create a new subclass of CALayer that has an animatable property called 'progress'.

Your snippet does indeed have a property called 'progress'

```
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat progress;
```

It appears the animation is animating that property

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `progress` is an animatable property for this specific uiview. We could custom animatable property refer: [Create a custom animatable property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192816/create-a-custom-animatable-property)