# Swift4 Animation using Timer.scheduledTimer

Tags: swift, animation, timer

I'm animating a clock hand that takes a CGFloat value from 0 to 1.  While I have the animation, I would like it to be a lot smoother.  The total animation takes 5 seconds, as part of an input variable.  How can I make this a lot smoother?

Ideally, I'd like to get all the values from 0 to 1 in 5 seconds...

The clock hand does a complete 360 but is a little choppy

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(launchTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    launchTimer()
}

 func launchTimer()  {

    guard seconds < 4.9 else {

        timer.invalidate()
        seconds = 0

        return
    }

    seconds += 0.1

    clockView.currentPressure = CGFloat(seconds / 5)
    clockView.setNeedsDisplay()

}
```

EDIT

```
import UIKit

class GaugeView: UIView {

    var currentPressure : CGFloat = 0.0

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        StyleKitName.drawGauge(pressure: currentPressure)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Timer` is not appropriate for animations on this scale. 100ms isn't a good step in any case, since it's not a multiple of the frame rate (16.67ms). Generally speaking, you shouldn't try to hand-animate unless you have a specialized problem. See `UIView.animate(withDuration:...)`, which is generally how you should animate UI elements, allowing the system to take care of the progress for you.

For a slightly more manual animation, see `CABasicAnimation`, which will update a property over time. If you need very manual control, see `CADisplayLink`, but you almost never need this.

In any case, you must never assume that any timer is called precisely when you ask it to be. You cannot add 0.1s to a value just because you asked to be called in 0.1s. You have to look at what time it really is. Even hard-real-time systems can't promise something will be called at a precise moment. The best you can possibly get is a promise it will be within some tolerance (and iOS doesn't even give you that).

---

To animate this with `UIView` (which I recommend), it'll probably be something like:

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    self.clockView.currentPressure = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: {
         self.clockView.currentPressure = 1
    })
}
```

With a `CABasicAnimation` (which is more complicated) it would be something like:

```
currentPressure = 1 // You have to set it to where it's going or it'll snap back.
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "currentPressure")
anim.fromValue = 0
anim.toValue = 1
anim.duration = 5
clockView.addAnimation(anim)
```

Comment: Rob, thanks for the explanation.  How would I use `CABasicAnimation` in my example?

Comment: It depends on what `currentPressure` is. What's the desired range, and does modifying it automatically update the view?

Comment: See edit above.  The desired range is from 0 to 1.  Changing the value automatically updates the view...

Comment: The only problem with `UIView.animate(withDuration` is it won't animate from 0 to 1 because `currentPressure` is not an animatable property, like alpha, bounds or frame.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192816/create-a-custom-animatable-property for how to make arbitrary values be animatable. An even more explicit tutorial: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/07/custom-property-uiview-block-animation/

Answer (score 0):

Make the time interval smaller to make the animation smoother. That way it will seem like it's gliding around instead of jumping between values.

You can also use spritekit:

```
import SpriteKit

let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.01)
let runAnim = SKAction.run {
    launchTimer()
}
let n = SKNode()
n.run(SKAction.repeat(SKAction.sequence([wait, runAnim]), count: 500))
```

Comment: timeInterval: 0.1 is the smallest allowable value.

Comment: Never using SpriteKit before, I'm not sure how this will move the clock arm (update the `clockView.currentPressure`  Is this supposed to replace my timer?

Comment: Instead of `timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(launchTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)` add the code above. It serves as a a timer but allows smaller time intervals.

Comment: You will also want to change `seconds += 0.1` to `seconds += 0.01` (or whatever value to match the value in `SKAction.wait`).

Comment: `self.launchTimer() never gets called..`